# proving continuity of a function from f(x+h) and f(x-h)

Tags: limits, continuity

Let f be such that lim as h approaches 0 of:
    (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) = 0
for all real numbers x. Does this imply that f is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

No. By that definition

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

Every (equivalent) definition of continuity at a point has to refer one way or another to the value of the function at that point. Your candidate definition does not and that's why it runs into trouble.